# Images won't display when I call the isRunning() method on my Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

This is my first time in this forum. I have a problem with java timer.My program shows images at different time.this is my code

```
//TIMER
    //creo timer per il tempo di visualizzazione di ogni singola immagine
    timerDisplay = new Timer(this.timeOfImage * MILLE, this);
    timerDisplay.setRepeats(false);
    timerDisplay.setActionCommand("blackScreen");

    //timer tra le immagini
    timerBetweenImages = new Timer(this.timeBetwImage * MILLE,this);
    timerBetweenImages.setRepeats(false);
    timerBetweenImages.setActionCommand("image");
    //timer prima della scelta
    timerBeforeChoice = new Timer(this.timeBeforeChoice * MILLE,this);
    timerBeforeChoice.setRepeats(false);
    timerBeforeChoice.setActionCommand("Choice");
    //tempo di scelta
    timerChoice = new Timer(this.timeOfChoice * MILLE,this);
    timerChoice.setRepeats(false);
    timerChoice.setActionCommand("End");


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // tempo tra immagini consecutive
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("blackScreen")) {

        label.setIcon(null);
        if (index != numOfImages) {
        timerBetweenImages.start();



        } else {

            label.setIcon(null);
            timerBeforeChoice.start();
        }
    //to see the images
    } else if (index < numOfImages && e.getActionCommand().equals("image")){ 

        label.setIcon(image[index]);

        index++;
        //visualizza

        timerDisplay.start();

        state();

    } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Choice")) {

        contentPane.remove(label);
        //modifico il layout per inserire tanti pannelli quanto sono le immagini
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, this.numOfImages));
        repaint();
        validate();
        //creo tanti pannelli quante sono le immagini da visualizzare



           //creo pannello
           JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
           panel1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
           //aggiungo immagine e checkbox al pannello
           JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
           lblNewLabel_1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           lblNewLabel_1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
           lblNewLabel_1.setIcon(image[i]);
           panel1.add(lblNewLabel_1);
           i++;
           chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Immagine " + 1);
           chckbxNewCheckBox.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           chckbxNewCheckBox.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
           chckbxNewCheckBox.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
           chckbxNewCheckBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
           panel1.add(chckbxNewCheckBox);
          contentPane.add(panel1);  
        //creo pannello
           JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
           panel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
           //aggiungo immagine e checkbox al pannello
           JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("");
           lblNewLabel_2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           lblNewLabel_2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
           lblNewLabel_2.setIcon(image[i]);
           panel2.add(lblNewLabel_2);
           i++;
           chckbxNewCheckBox2 = new JCheckBox("Immagine " + 2);
           chckbxNewCheckBox2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
           chckbxNewCheckBox2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
           chckbxNewCheckBox2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
           chckbxNewCheckBox2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
           panel2.add(chckbxNewCheckBox2);
           //i++;
           //aggiungo pannello al contentPane
          contentPane.add(panel2);  
           repaint();
           validate();
            chckbxNewCheckBox2.addItemListener(this);
         chckbxNewCheckBox.addItemListener(this);
         state();

     } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("End")) {

         contentPane.removeAll();
         repaint();
         validate();
         index = this.numOfImages;
         //System.out.println(index);
         this.numOfImages = this.numOfImages + number;
         //System.out.println(numOfImages);
         contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
         contentPane.add(label);
         if (numOfImages <= image.length) {
             timerDisplay.start();
         } else {
             //CHIUDI CONNESSIONE
             Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EmoStateFree(eState);
             Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EmoEngineEventFree(eEvent);
             Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EngineDisconnect();
             dispose();
         }

     }
```

Then I have this method:

```
public void state(){
    while(timerDisplay.isRunning()){

    state = Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EngineGetNextEvent(eEvent);
    // New event needs to be handled

    if (state == EdkErrorCode.EDK_OK.ToInt()) {

        int eventType = Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EmoEngineEventGetType(eEvent);
        Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EmoEngineEventGetUserId(eEvent, userID);

        // Log the EmoState if it has been updated
        if (eventType == Edk.EE_Event_t.EE_EmoStateUpdated.ToInt()) {

            Edk.INSTANCE.EE_EmoEngineEventGetEmoState(eEvent, eState);
            //tempo
            float timestamp = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_GetTimeFromStart(eState);
            //user ID
            int user =  userID.getValue();

            //valori emotional
            float shortExcitement = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_AffectivGetExcitementShortTermScore(eState);
            float longExcitement = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_AffectivGetExcitementLongTermScore(eState);
            float egagement = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_AffectivGetEngagementBoredomScore(eState);
            float frustation = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_AffectivGetFrustrationScore(eState);
            float meditation = EmoState.INSTANCE.ES_AffectivGetMeditationScore(eState);
            if(option == 1){
                output.println(timestamp + ";" + user + ";" + shortExcitement + ";"  +
                         longExcitement + ";" + egagement + ";" + frustation + ";" + meditation + ";");
            } else if (option == 2){
                output.println(timestamp + ";" + user + ";" + shortExcitement + ";"  +
                         longExcitement + ";" + egagement + ";" + frustation + ";" + meditation + ";");
            }


        }

    }
    else if (state != EdkErrorCode.EDK_NO_EVENT.ToInt()) {
        output.println("Internal error in Emotiv Engine!");
        //messaggio di errore
        String message2 = "Internal error in Emotiv Engine!";
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message2, "Dialog",
           JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
}
```

The problem is in my `state()` method, when I call `timerDisplay.isRunning()` the program can't show the images. In fact, I want `state()` to run until `timerDisplay` finishes. Sorry for my bad english... :)

Comment: That's because your blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. What's the purpose of the state method?

Comment: it stamps Affectiv Values in a .csv file. It works(beacuse writes values in csv file) but only one time if i remove while(timerDisplay.isRunning()).But if i use the code that i have posted,the application can't display any images.How can solve this problem?What i have to change in my app?

Answer (score 2):

Your `state` method appears to be block the Event Dispatching Thread.  This prevents any events (include paint and timer events) from been processed, making it appear as if your application has stopped.

This occurs because Swing is a single threaded environment.  This means that all interaction with the UI must be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  It also means you should be performing all blocking or time consuming processing on another thread.

Take a look at [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).  This will allow you to process you "state" events within a background thread, but also has easy to use methods to re-sync any updates to the UI/EDT.

Also have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information

Comment: ok,thanks!i'm trying to modify my app in this way.I try tomorrow and then i'll write here,if i have some problems :) Thanks a lot

Comment: If this task does not modify any Swing components,can i use a thread like Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            while(timerDisplay.isRunning(){ //do something}

        }
    }
});